# using a Powershell Script to maximize a window to the left or right (not full screen)

Tags: powershell, input, screen, keystroke, maximize

I seen some pretty similar questions to this when searching but I am not very familiar with "VB script" so they didn't really help me. I'm using power shell to open multiple applications and that is no issue but I'd like to have two of them maximize to the left and right side of the screen so I can see them both at the same time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your code so far? What is the expected output, and what happens instead?

Comment: I think this depends very much of the application you are opening and how you are opening them. It would help very much to see some code and, if possible, to know which applications.

Comment: the following example may give you some hints: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1739320-powershell-manipulate-window-size-and-position-ps4 it works for IE windows

Comment: start-process "c:\windows\system32\devmgmt.msc"
sleep 1
start-process "c:\windows\system32\sysdm.cpl"       then after these two apps open I would like them both to be maximized to right and left sides of the screen. sorry for the late reply!